# I'm saddenned that I was not allowed to post an answer

Tags: discussion

I want to give a good answer to the question about being called "queer"

But y'all have decided to block me with no warning. Shame on you.

Answer (score 21):

Your block was not imposed manually by any user or moderator.

It was imposed by the system due to the fact that you have several heavily downvoted and deleted answers. Five out of your seven answers were deleted for quality reasons, leaving only two.

Users who show a repeated disregard for post quality here are blocked from posting. We have attempted to guide you with suggestions of how to improve your answers but you have disregarded them, opting instead to leave them for us to clean up.

Please, if you would like to continue to answer questions here, edit your deleted answers so that they can be undeleted and you may regain the ability to post answers. Information on how to do this is provided [here](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans).

For more information, see [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/274942) This post clearly outlines the ramifications of being answer banned and how to get out of that state.